# Конфликт HTML5 валидации и jQuery Mask Plugin

Tags: jquery, html5, валидация

Делаю небольшую форму обратной связи. Для проверки валидности вводимых в поля "Имя", "Телефон" и "Текст сообщения" данных использую HTML5 валидацию.

Код формы:

```
<form action="/send.php" method="get" class="feedback-form">
    <input type="text" required="" placeholder="ваше имя ..." name="USER_NAME" id="user-name"><br>
    <input type="text" required="" placeholder="ваш телефон ..." name="USER_PHONE" id="user-phone" maxlength="18" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <textarea required="" placeholder="текст сообщения ..." name="USER_MESSAGE"></textarea><br>
    <input align="right" type="submit" value="Отправить" name="submit"><br>
</form>
```

Для облегчения ввода в поле "Телефон" данных использую [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) с такими параметрами маски:

```
$root.find('#user-phone').mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99");
```

Проблема в том, что при таком сочетании HTML5 валидация ругается на поле ввода телефона, пока туда ничего не ввели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема? Как победить эту несуразицу?

Comment: У всех `input`'ов тип указан как `text`, так что не очень понятно что может не понравиться HTML5 валидации. Более того, в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLo016p9/1/) всё выглядит нормально.

Comment: Действительно странно...

Comment: @maler1988 Здравствуйте! Кажется все очевидно, у вас атрибут `required` стоит у `input` с телефоном. Данный атрибут делает поле обязательным для заполнения. **Ваш вопрос:** «_HTML5 валидация ругается на поле ввода телефона, пока туда ничего не ввели_» **Ответ:** конечно, ведь вы сами сделали обязательным для заполнения данный `input`. Когда он пустой и срабатывает сообщение об ошибке. Всего вам доброго!